# Bootstrap: dropdown menu covers content

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My code is save at http://jsfiddle.net/qba2xgh6/1/ , it comes from the Bootstrap official website.

Below is the code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">My Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container main">
  <p>
    Hello, the main content starts here.
    Hello, the main content starts here.
    Hello, the main content starts here.
    Hello, the main content starts here.
    Hello, the main content starts here.
    Hello, the main content starts here.Hello, the main content starts here.
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I clicked the dropdown button at the right upper corner, the dropdown menu appears and covers the main content. How can I avoid this? I would like it to push down the main content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you are using the class `navbar-fixed-top` that makes the navbar stay fixed -- out of the flow on the document. You can:

- Remove that class. But it will delete the behavior on all devices and resolutions too.
- If you want to keep that for all but not for mobile then add this media query:

  ```
  @media (max-width:768px) {
      .main {
          margin-top:0;
      }
      .navbar-fixed-top {
          position:static;
      }
  }
  ```

Check this **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qba2xgh6/2/)**

Comment: Sorry, the `position:static;` doesn't seem to work. I have added a lot more bunch of text to test it. See http://jsfiddle.net/qba2xgh6/5/  The navbar scroll away together with the text.

Comment: @shapeare obviusly because it isn't fixed anymore ... i f you want it to be fixed after scroll will need jquery too.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the class `navbar-fixed-top` from the outermost `<div>`

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing the intended behaviour for the `fixed navigation`. If you remove the `.navbar-fixed-top` class on the navigation it removes the 'stickiness' of the navigation and it'll follow the content flow.

You can a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/qba2xgh6/4/ , I also removed the margin from the .main as it's not needed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue when I first started using Bootstrap. When you use the class `navbar-fixed-top` the navbar will stay at the top of the page. Remove this and then it'll work as expected.