# Navbar Dropdown list hidden under second Navbar using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm currently making a navbar menu for a website, with some sections having a sub-menu.
My issue is that the **sub-menu** is displaying over the **dropdowns** from the top menu.

Here are the classes for the first navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
</nav>
```

And the second:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
</nav>
```

I've tried playing with the Z-Index, which is currently higher on my dropdown list than on the sub-menu, but still no luck displaying the dropdown over it.

This feels like a simple thing, but I can't get this to work, and I've had no luck finding a solution online.

Any help with be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer in this post had the solution:

[Bootstrap: dropdown menu covers content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191212/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-covers-content)

I had to add:

```
nav.navbar-static-top {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: static;
}
```

To my CSS and it fixed it. 
It sounds weird that you'd need to add position:static to a class who's name is static, but I'm glad it works!